# Why are my FedEx Web Services rates different than the web site?

Tags: fedex

I'm using the FedEx Web Services to get rates.  The rates my script returns are always slightly wrong vs the rates from the FedEx "Get Rates" web site at https://www.fedex.com/ratefinder/home

No matter what I do my values are always slightly off.  Does anyone know why this might be?  For example a 20 lbs 10x10x10 inch package from 14305 to 98052 by FIRST_OVERNIGHT is $237.36 with a Base Rate of $214.45 from the ratefinder web site above.

But my web services script gives this, none of these numbers can be used to get the same $237.36 value.  What am I missing?

```
[Version] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [ServiceId] => crs
                            [Major] => 13
                            [Intermediate] => 0
                            [Minor] => 0
                        )

                    [RateReplyDetails] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [ServiceType] => FIRST_OVERNIGHT
                            [PackagingType] => YOUR_PACKAGING
                            [DeliveryStation] => OTSA 
                            [DeliveryDayOfWeek] => MON
                            [DeliveryTimestamp] => 20161212T090000
                            [CommitDetails] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [ServiceType] => FIRST_OVERNIGHT
                                    [CommitTimestamp] => 20161212T090000
                                    [DayOfWeek] => MON
                                    [DestinationServiceArea] => A4
                                    [BrokerToDestinationDays] => 0
                                    [DocumentContent] => NON_DOCUMENTS
                                )

                            [DestinationAirportId] => SEA
                            [IneligibleForMoneyBackGuarantee] => false
                            [OriginServiceArea] => A4
                            [DestinationServiceArea] => A4
                            [SignatureOption] => SERVICE_DEFAULT
                            [ActualRateType] => PAYOR_ACCOUNT_PACKAGE
                            [RatedShipmentDetails] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [ShipmentRateDetail] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [RateType] => PAYOR_ACCOUNT_PACKAGE
                                                    [RateScale] => 18
                                                    [RateZone] => 8
                                                    [PricingCode] => PACKAGE
                                                    [RatedWeightMethod] => ACTUAL
                                                    [DimDivisor] => 166
                                                    [FuelSurchargePercent] => 3.0
                                                    [TotalBillingWeight] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [Units] => LB
                                                            [Value] => 20.0
                                                        )

                                                    [TotalBaseCharge] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [Currency] => USD
                                                            [Amount] => 201.72
                                                        )

                                                    [TotalFreightDiscounts] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [Currency] => USD
                                                            [Amount] => 0.0
                                                        )

                                                    [TotalNetFreight] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [Currency] => USD
                                                            [Amount] => 201.72
                                                        )

                                                    [TotalSurcharges] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [Currency] => USD
                                                            [Amount] => 22.53
                                                        )

                                                    [TotalNetFedExCharge] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [Currency] => USD
                                                            [Amount] => 224.25
                                                        )

                                                    [TotalTaxes] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [Currency] => USD
                                                            [Amount] => 0.0
                                                        )

                                                    [TotalNetCharge] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [Currency] => USD
                                                            [Amount] => 224.25
                                                        )

                                                    [TotalRebates] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [Currency] => USD
                                                            [Amount] => 0.0
                                                        )

                                                    [TotalDutiesAndTaxes] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [Currency] => USD
                                                            [Amount] => 0.0
                                                        )

                                                    [TotalNetChargeWithDutiesAndTaxes] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [Currency] => USD
                                                            [Amount] => 224.25
                                                        )

                                                    [Surcharges] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [SurchargeType] => SATURDAY_PICKUP
                                                                    [Description] => Saturday pickup
                                                                    [Amount] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                        (
                                                                            [Currency] => USD
                                                                            [Amount] => 16.0
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [SurchargeType] => FUEL
                                                                    [Description] => Fuel
                                                                    [Amount] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                                        (
                                                                            [Currency] => USD
                                                                            [Amount] => 6.53
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )
```

Comment: My bet would be state or local taxes. This might be best asked through their own support channels, though - questions about the internal workings of proprietary APIs aren't really on topic here.

Comment: Try checking "Ship using FedEx account", then use detailed quote after logging in with the same credentials that you provided when signing up for WS access. This way the web site should display the same discounted rate that WS returns.